# Isolated singularity of harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am working with a book by Axler, Bourdon and Ramey and find the following problem:

Suppose $u$ is a harmonic function on $B \setminus \{0 \}$ such that
$$   |x|^{n-2} u(x) \to 0, \qquad x \to 0 $$
Prove that $u$ has a removable singularity at $0$

The solution is trivial if you consider Laurent series. I have been told that the proof is much more elementary just by considering Poisson's kernel. Does anybody know it?

Thank you in advance,

D

Comment: Hint: build a real solution in ball by Poisson's kernel and compare two solutions by max principle.

Comment: Is the book perhaps named "Harmonic funtion theory"?

Comment: @D G: Could you please sketch why the proof is trivial using Laurent series? How do you prove the analogue for n=2 with the logarithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the ball $B$ has radius $1$ and $n\ge 3$. Take $r\in (0,1)$ and consider the problem

$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 -\Delta v=0, &\mbox{ in $B(0,r)$}, \\
  v=u, &\mbox{in $\partial B(0,r)$}.
       \end{array} \right.
$$

I - Show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{u(x)-v(x)}{r^{2-n}-|x|^{2-n}}=0.$$

II - From I, we have that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that $$|u(x)-v(x)|\le \epsilon |r^{2-n}-|x|^{2-n}|,\ \forall\ x\in \overline{B(0,\delta)}.\tag{1}$$

Use the maximum principle in the domain $B(0,1)\setminus B(0,\delta)$, to conclude an inequality similiar to $(1)$ for this domain.

III - Conclude that $u=v$.

Comment: (1) can't be correct, since $r^{2-n}-|x|^{2-n} \le 0$ for $|x|\le \delta < r$. @Tomás

Comment: You prefer to downvote my answer, instead of correct it? Now, is it fine?

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually post here. I didn't know how to make a notification pop. Already removed downvote. Still don't see how this is useful as $|x|^{2-n} \to \infty$. So the problem at zero remains. Can you post a complete proof? @Tomás

Comment: @DG, Have you concluded $(1)$ for all $x\in \overline{B(0,1)}$?

Comment: Yes, first by the limit, then by the macimun principle I can bound by $\delta^{n-2}-r^{n-2}$ on the complement of B(0,r)

Comment: Ok, now to conclude, you can use the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, therefore, $|u(x)-v(x)|\le 0$ for all $x$ in the ball.